# Phone Number Validator

Tags: javascript, html, regex, validation

I have this code which validates the phone number:

```
function phvalid() {
    var regexObj = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
    if (regexObj.test(subjectString)) {
        var formattedPhoneNumber = subjectString.replace(regexObj, "($1) $2-$3");
    } else {
        alert("Invalid Number");
    }
}
```

I'm trying to validate it into the body of the following html code:

```
<p class="normal">Phone:
    <input type='text' id='ph' />
    <input type='button' onclick="phvalid();" value="Click" />
</p>
```

Is this function right or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You might also consider using `input type='tel'` http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.tel.html

Comment: But also bear in mind that if you want this to work world-wide there's probably not much you can do to validate.

Answer (score 4):

You never define `subjectString`

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/bfvXL/1/

```
function phvalid() {

    var regexObj = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
    var subjectString = document.getElementById("ph").value;
    if (regexObj.test(subjectString))

    {
        var formattedPhoneNumber = subjectString.replace(regexObj, "($1) $2-$3");
    } else {
        alert("Invalid Number");
    }

}
```

This will run your function, but I'm not sure what your intention is with the `formattedPhoneNumber` block.

Also, you'll need to make sure that your onclick can access this. So you'll have to put your js within your body or within a block that gets ran after the dom is loaded.

**Edit**: I believe this is what you want with your `formattedPhoneNumber`: http://jsfiddle.net/bfvXL/2/

**Edit2:** For new requirement in comment below... try this: http://jsfiddle.net/bfvXL/3/

```
function phvalid() {
    var subjectString = document.getElementById("ph").value;
    subjectString = subjectString.replace(/[^\d]/g, "");
    if (subjectString.length == 10) {
        var regexObj = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
        var formattedPhoneNumber = subjectString.replace(regexObj, "($1) $2-$3");
        document.getElementById("ph").value = formattedPhoneNumber;
    } else {
        alert("Invalid Number");
    }
}
```

and actually since `regexObj` isn't being used for validation in this case, you could simply just have it as `/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/`

Comment: Thanks!! works great! how would i make the value limit to 10 numbers instead of using 3-3-4?

Comment: Why? You want to be able to have like `1sfalj2n3nio4567sdaf890jl`?

Answer (score 0):

see very generic phone number-fax number validation code- hope it will be useful
http://oracleadf-java.blogspot.in/2013/05/phone-number-custom-validation-in-adf.html

public void phoneNoValidator
(FacesContext facesContext, 
UIComponent uIComponent, 
Object object) {

```
    String msg2 = "";
    if (object != null) {
        String phnNo = object.toString();
        int openB = 0;
        int closeB = 0;
        boolean closeFg = false;
        char[] xx = phnNo.toCharArray();
        for (char c : xx) {
            if (c == '(') {
                openB = openB + 1;
            } else if (c == ')') {
                closeB = closeB + 1;
            }

            if (closeB > openB) {
                closeFg = true; //closed brackets will not be more than open brackets at any given time.
            }
        }
        //if openB=0 then no. of closing and opening brackets equal || opening bracket must always come before closing brackets
        //closing brackets must not come before first occurrence of openning bracket
        if (openB != closeB || closeFg == true || (phnNo.lastIndexOf("(") > phnNo.lastIndexOf(")")) ||
            (phnNo.indexOf(")") < phnNo.indexOf("("))) {
            msg2 = "Brackets not closed properly.";
            FacesMessage message2 = new FacesMessage(msg2);
            message2.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
            throw new ValidatorException(message2);
        }
        if (phnNo.contains("()")) {
            msg2 = "Empty Brackets are not allowed.";
            FacesMessage message2 = new FacesMessage(msg2);
            message2.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
            throw new ValidatorException(message2);
        }
        if (phnNo.contains("(.") || phnNo.contains("(-") || phnNo.contains("-)")) {
            msg2 = "Invalid Phone Number.Check content inside brackets.";
            FacesMessage message2 = new FacesMessage(msg2);
            message2.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
            throw new ValidatorException(message2);
        }

        openB = 0;
        closeB = 0;
        closeFg = false;
        //check for valid language name.Allowed- brackets,dots,hyphen

        String expression = "([0-9\\-\\+\\(\\)]+)";
        CharSequence inputStr = phnNo;
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
        String error = "Invalid Phone Number";
        System.out.println("Index of plus is--->" + phnNo.lastIndexOf("+"));
        System.out.println("Bracket index--->" + phnNo.charAt(0));

        if (matcher.matches()) {
            if (phnNo.contains("++") || phnNo.contains("--")) {
                throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, error,
                                                              "Can not contain two hyphen(--) or plus(++)"));
            } else if (phnNo.lastIndexOf("+") > 1) {
                throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, error,
                                                              "Plus sign should be in proper place"));
            } else if (phnNo.lastIndexOf("+") == 1 && phnNo.charAt(0) != '(') {
                throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, error,
                                                              "Plus sign should be in proper place"));
            } else if (phnNo.startsWith(" ") || phnNo.endsWith(" ")) {
                throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, error,
                                                              "Space Not allowed at start and end"));
            }

        } else {
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, error,
                                                          "Only numeric character,+,() and - allowed"));
        }

    }
}
```